# Pass **kwargs through to inner function

Tags: python

I have a function

```
def wrapper_function(url, **kwargs)
   def foo():
      if kwargs:
          return do_something(url, kwargs)
      else:
          return do_something(url)
```

The `do_something()` function can either have one or more parameters.

When I call the `wrapper_function()`, want to call it either like

```
wrapper_function('www.bar.com')
```

or

```
wrapper_function('www.bar.com', selected_clients=clients)
```

so that `do_something('www.bar.com', selected_clients=clients)`.

However, when I approach it like this, I get an error
`clients is not defined`.

How can I pass on the params exactly like they are with the keyword into an inner function? Important, that keyword needs to be variable as well.

Comment: `return do_something(url, **kwargs)`

Comment: You need to *unpack* `kwargs` with `**`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

When your function takes in kwargs in the form `foo(**kwargs)`, you access the keyworded arguments as you would a python dict. Similarly, to pass the dict to a function in the form of several keyworded arguments, simply pass it as `**kwargs` again. So, in your case,

```
do_something(url, **kwargs)
```